# F# LINQ Aggregate operators code difference

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, f#

I am learning LINQ in F# 3.0, try to follow some samples on internet.
One sample I found was LINQ sample for C# - LINQ Aggregate operators.
This sample uses Max to get the most expensive price among each category's products.

The following code is in C#:

```cs
public void Linq87()
{
  List<Product> products = GetProductList();

  var categories =
    from p in products
    group p by p.Category into g
    select new { Category = g.Key, MostExpensivePrice = g.Max(p => p.UnitPrice) };

  ObjectDumper.Write(categories);
}
```

Result:

```
Category=Beverages
Category=Condiments
Category=Produce
Category=Meat/Poultry
Category=Seafood
Category=Dairy Products
Category=Confections
Category=Grains/Cereals     
MostExpensivePrice=263.5000
MostExpensivePrice=43.9000
MostExpensivePrice=53.0000
MostExpensivePrice=123.7900
MostExpensivePrice=62.5000
MostExpensivePrice=55.0000
MostExpensivePrice=81.0000
MostExpensivePrice=38.0000
```

However, the syntax is totally different in F#.
In F#, I tried something like this:

```ml
let expensiveProducts =
    query {
          for p in products do
          groupValBy p.Category into g
          select ( g )
          }
```

But I don't understand the result.
The C# syntax for LINQ: "select new" do not work in F#.
Anyone can figure it out?
I believe the code in C# and F# should be not quite different, but I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

*Your `groupValBy` operator is incorrect*. You have to provide both a value (`p`) and a key (`p.Category`) for grouping.

There's no such thing like C#'s anonymous type in F#; a simple alternative is using tuples:

```
let expensiveProducts =
    query {
          for p in products do
          groupValBy p p.Category into g // groupByVal has two arguments here
          select (g.Key, g.Max(fun (p: Product) -> p.UnitPrice))
          }
```

If you would like to have explicit field names in results, the way to go is declaring a record type:

```
// MostExpensivePrice is nullable due to the return type of g.Max
type Result = { Category: string; MostExpensivePrice: Nullable<int> }
```

and the `select` operator should look like this:

```
select { Category = g.Key; 
         MostExpensivePrice = g.Max(fun (p: Product) -> p.UnitPrice) }
```

Comment: Hi, Pad:
Thank you very much for your help.
However, since I don't know what is returned for the function in the C# code:
List<Product> products = GetProductList();
Therefore, I can not test.
But I download database sample: AdventureWorksLT, and try your code with SalesLT.Product table.
I still got 25 compiler errors.
Can you create a simple test data table and test your code?
Thanks,
John

Comment: @JohnJohn: In this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374(v=vs.110).aspx) they have one example using `groupValBy`. Please use the database and the example there as a starting point, and try to apply my answer.

Comment: Hi, Pad:
I have tried to use the MSDN example of "Student" as from the web line you provided.  The only thing working is the groupValBy for function "Count(*)", but there is no function "Max(*)", your code can not got compiled.  I still got 25 compiler errors
Can you show me the data table records for your code to work on?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have figured this out.
Let me use database sample: AdventureWorksLT, for SalesLT.Product table.  I can use the following SQL statement to get some Max(*) values:
    SELECT ProductCategoryID, MAX(ListPrice) AS Max_Prix FROM SalesLT.Product GROUP BY ProductCategoryID

The following is the results from SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio:

```
ProductCategoryID    Max_Prix
5          3399.99
6          3578.27
7          2384.07
8          120.27
9          121.49
10          106.50
11          20.24
12          404.99
13          121.46
14          229.49
15          124.73
16          1364.50
17          80.99
18          1431.50
19          52.64
20          1003.91
21          357.06
22          89.99
23          8.99
24          37.99
25          53.99
26          69.99
27          9.50
28          74.99
29          63.50
30          120.00
31          159.00
32          9.99
33          7.95
34          21.98
35          34.99
36          54.99
37          44.99
38          25.00
39          125.00
40          24.99
41          35.00
```

The following is my code in F# doing the same job:

```
#light
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open System.Linq

[<Literal>]
let connString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT;Integrated Security=True"
[<Generate>] 
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<connString>
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext() 

let expensiveProducts =
    query {
          for p in db.SalesLT_Product do
          groupValBy p.ListPrice p.ProductCategoryID into g
          let maxPrice = query { for mp in g do
                                 maxBy mp }
          select (g.Key, maxPrice)
          }
          |> Seq.toArray

let showExpensiveProducts = expensiveProducts
printfn "%A" showExpensiveProducts
printfn "OK"
```

The following is the result:

```
[|(5, 3399.9900M); (6, 3578.2700M); (7, 2384.0700M); 
  (8, 120.2700M); (9, 121.4900M); (10, 106.5000M); 
  (11, 20.2400M); (12, 404.9900M); (13, 121.4600M); 
  (14, 229.4900M); (15, 124.7300M); (16, 1364.5000M);
  (17, 80.9900M); (18, 1431.5000M); (19, 52.6400M); 
  (20, 1003.9100M); (21, 357.0600M); (22, 89.9900M); 
  (23, 8.9900M); (24, 37.9900M); (25, 53.9900M);
  (26, 69.9900M); (27, 9.5000M); (28, 74.9900M); 
  (29, 63.5000M); (30, 120.0000M); (31, 159.0000M); 
  (32, 9.9900M); (33, 7.9500M); (34, 21.9800M); 
  (35, 34.9900M); (36, 54.9900M); (37, 44.9900M); 
  (38, 25.0000M); (39, 125.0000M); (40, 24.9900M); 
  (41, 35.0000M)|]
```

Thanks all for your help!
Have a nice day!
John